# Why is the person in the corner of this photo distorted?

Tags: distortion

Is it just me, or does the guy in the bottom left look really weird?  What is causing the distortion?

[image]
<sup>Anti-UK protesters outside the British embassy in Tehran on January 12, 2020. Atta Kenare/AFP/Getty Images</sup>

Comment: Looks like just about any smartphone camera.

Answer (score 7):

It's a typical result of rectilinear projection with a very wide angle lens. It's compounded by the hand being much closer, relatively, than the face to the camera.

Comment: Yes, wide angle rectilinear lenses will distort the edges of the frame, look at the size of his fist. If you are ever forced to shoot a group of people with a wide angle lens, don't put the overweight people on the ends!

Comment: @Mattman944 - Don't put any vain skinny people there either...